# Filenet Content Engine SECURITY_ANONYMOUS_DISALLOWED

Tags: websphere, jaas, filenet-content-engine

We have an development enviroment, with the AE and CE in the same websphere instance.
Now, we are trying to mount, the AE in one of our local machine, in a IRAD Websphere instance.
When the application tries to access filenet objects we get the following error:

> com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException:
>   SECURITY_ANONYMOUS_DISALLOWED: Anonymous users aren't allowed access
>   to the Content Engine. errorStack={ at
>   com.filenet.engine.context.SecurityContext.(SecurityContext.java:87)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.context.ServerCallContext.(ServerCallContext.java:87)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.context.ServerCallContext.newInstance(ServerCallContext.java:985)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.getUserName(RequestBrokerImpl.java:1300)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineCoreBean._getUserName(EngineCoreBean.java:731)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineCoreBean.getUserName(EngineCoreBean.java:713)
>   at
>   com.filenet.engine.ejb.EJSLocalStatelessEngineCore_22877cb1.getUserName(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineBean.processUserLicense(EngineBean.java:977)
>   at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineBean.methodInit(EngineBean.java:175)
>   at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineBean.getObjects(EngineBean.java:303)
>   at
>   com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs.EJSRemoteStatelessEngine_2e64c374.getObjects(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs._EJSRemoteStatelessEngine_2e64c374_Tie.getObjects(_EJSRemoteStatelessEngine_2e64c374_Tie.java:184)
>   at
>   com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs._EJSRemoteStatelessEngine_2e64c374_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemoteStatelessEngine_2e64c374_Tie.java:98)
>   at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:613)
>   at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:466)
>   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:503) at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1552) at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2673) at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2551) at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62) at
>   com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:95) at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)

We've already:

- Configured the same JAAS as in the dev env.
- Installed a certificate from our local machine in the Websphere instance.
- We've enabled the administrative security and the application security
- The LDAP configuration is the same as in the AE on the dev env
- The primary administrative user name is the same in both AE and CE

We are using **Websphere 6.1**.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention setting up a trust relationship (LTPA keys) between the two WAS instances.  That can lead to these symptoms.

Comment: Yes, we've exported the LTPA keys from both sides and imported them, the result is the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the exact reason as there are not enough details about your environment. There might various causes for the exception that you are seeing.

In general, all nuts and bolts are described in the following document – [Problems with Anonymous principal UNAUTHENTICATED when using the Java API](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21307871). You should not have problems with authentication if you follow the instructions provided there.

Answer (score -1):

Try one simple thing and check the proper `string` value where you specify the path of :

```
1)abc=file:/c:/WebSphere/AppClient/properties/sas.client.props
2)xyz=C:\jaas.conf.WebSphere
```

The format should be exactly the same as above for respective files.

This was the most basic problem which I had faced.